# .NET string split method strange behavior

Tags: .net, string, split

I have a problem with string.split using.NET 3.5:

String to split is:

```
dim source as string = "ab|foo|bar|bar|bar-foo|ab|ezrezertr|ghghhjhj|ab|foo|xxx|"
dim result() as string = source.split("ab|")
```

When used within a Winforms applicaton, the result is "correct":

result(0) is "foo|bar|bar|bar-foo|"

result(1) is "ezrezertr|ghghhjhj|"

result(2) is "foo|xxx|"

And I'm happy!

When used within an ASP.NET code behind, the result is:

result(0) is "b|foo|bar|bar|bar-foo|"

result(1) is "b|ezrezertr|ghghhjhj|"

result(2) is "b|foo|xxx|"

In other words, the split function only get rid of the 1st character of the separator string!
Does someone know why?

Comment: There is no difference where are you using Split() method in WinForms, Console or ASP.NET application. System.String class is the same everywhere. Problem is in you code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASP.NET results look like you are using [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) rather than [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx). The string `"ab|"` will be interpreted as a regular expression for "a" followed by "b" or nothing, so just an "a" matches.

---

Later: ***Second Theory***:

- There is no overload of `String.Split` that takes a single string argument. The only single argument overload takes an array of `char`.
- `String.Splt(char())` will split on *any* of the passed characters.
- VB, without `Option Strict On` will implicitly convert a string to an array of chars.

Hence I think in the ASP.NET case you don't have `option strict on`, therefore `theString.Split(anotherString)` is being treated as `theString.Split(anotherString.ToCharArray())`.

Thus splitting on just a `"b"`.

However this leaves the question of how the first cases acts as passing a string, but there is no overload taking a `String()` without extra parameters (a `SplitOptions`)...

Summary: Visual Basic's extra implicit conversions and behaviour set at a file/project/language level can make identical code behave differently.

Comment: The issue is I have just copy-pasted a function from Winforms code to ASP code-behind and I could then observe the result, which is as described. On the very same computer or on a hosted server makes no difference! And that code uses string.split and no regex!

Comment: @Didier: I like to think I'm unique, but I claim no special knowledge. Just lots of experience fixing misunderstandings.... and I have a second theory here.

Comment: Thanks Richard, your "second theory" must be the right one and it explains the difference in behavior. Therefore, in order to fix the issue, I need to do a string = replace(string,"ab|","#") and then split the result on the "#" char... Provided this "#" char used as separator doesn't exists anywhere in the string, which is the case. Not absolutely perfect but t will do the job.

Comment: @Didier: Or explictly pass the argument as an array of strings (in C# this would be `new [] { "ab|" }`) to avoid string to char() conversion. Setting `option strict on` would be even better but the rest of the code may depend on it being off.

Answer (score 2):

If the input string is the same, then I can nearly guarantee you that the split method of a Console app and ASP.NET behave the same.

Maybe the output is not displayed correctly?

Comment: Hey Richard, you must be a very rare person, one that is capable to guarantee Microsoft code? LOL...